# Loop to replace "x" in whole code with list of different replacements

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R and I'm little stuck right now.
So, I wrote code that looks like this (this is only the beginning):

```
# Load all EUR Files
setwd(EUR)
filenames <- list.files(path = EUR)
MSCIeur <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ";"))
```

Now I need to run this code several times for different currencies, so my question is: Is there a way to run the same code multiple times and the first time it runs it uses "EUR" the next time it replaces all "EUR" in the code with "USD" etc. or do I need to copy paste the whole code and just replace all "EUR" with "USD" manually?

Thx to anybody that took the time to read this :)

Comment: Look at `lapply` as your best option. A `for` loop can work, but is likely to be less efficient and require you to more explicitly store your results

Comment: One option would be to turn this whole thing into a function where `EUR` is replaced with something like `x` as a formal argument, and then you could call `lapply` where you provide it a vector of all the currencies to loop over and the name of the function.

Comment: @DanielAnderson Exactly that's what I also was thinking of, but i have a really hard time writing my own functions, but I give it a try :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `for` loop, you can set different working directories and store all your data inside a list:

```
curr.name <-  gsub(x = list.dirs('.', recursive=FALSE), pattern = "./", replacement ="")

curr <- paste(getwd(), curr.name, sep = "/")

___________________________________________________________________________________________

MSCI <- list()

for(i in 1:length(curr)){
  setwd(curr[i])
  filenames <- list.files(path = curr[i])
  MSCI[[i]] <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ";"))
}

names(MSCI) <- curr.name

___________________________________________________________________________________________

# Other way

for(i in 1:length(curr)){
  setwd(curr[i])
  filenames <- list.files(path = curr[i])
  assign(curr.name[i],do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ";")))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very sorry but I do not fully understand this code..   it somehow worked and created a list where all data frames of the other currencies are inside now.. but how do i split this afterwards into the individual data frames again, because i don't understand how to work with lists :/